# Best practice for user login after hashing and storing password in mysql with node bcrypt

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I just created a handler that stores a username and password in mysql. The handler function performs the standard bcrypt password hash:

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // Store hash in your password DB. 
});
```

Bcrypt also offers the standard code to compare the plaintext with the hash like so:

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true 
});
```

On an abstract level if I were to do the above compare function I would need to do the following:

- Get user input username and plain text password
- Send query to database SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'SomeName'
- Get back some username and hashed password
- Compare hashed password and authenticate user

The problem with that is that any user specific data cannot be retrieved before authentication so I will need to chain an additional query in order to retrieve any extra user sensitive data and this process would seem janky. And it seems unsafe because the client then has the hashed password at this point when there should be no need to bring back the password.

I would like to:

- Get user input username and plain text password
- Send query to database

  ```
  SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE username = 'SomeName' 
  AND password = COMPARISON_FUNCTION_THAT_WORKS_WITH_BCRYPT('plaintext')
  ```
- Get back some username and any user specific data
- and I am done

Am I completely missing the boat here, because if I am then what exactly are the 360k downloaders of this software doing for password encryption / user login process?

Comment: `because the client then has the hashed password at this point` - I don't understand why the client have the hashed password at this point? re-think the code

Comment: Ok then if that, why does bcrypt offer a seemingly useful password hash tool?

Comment: I must be confused due to the scarcity of code in your question - I see the node.js tag, so I gather node.js is the server side of things, and that connects to mysql and it's also the location where bcrypt is hashing the password - am I right so far? So what is the "client". Is that a web browser? Are you using bcrypt on the client side?

Comment: I am using bcrypt in the nodejs server side. I don't have a client yet so I am just cURLing in the terminal. Either way I am going to move the logic over to mongodb because it looks possible and there are solutions out there which use bcrypt.

Comment: You're probably overthinking this. If you can't even trust your server to temporarily have a password hash (in addition to the plaintext passwords which it has already) in memory, then what *can* you trust…?!

Answer (score 0):

You are not quite clear in the question what the problem is:

> I would like to:
>
> - Get user input username and plain text password
> - Send query to database
> - Get back some username and any user specific data
> - and I am done

That is exactly what you can do now.

- query for the user's info (including hashed password)
- check user supplied password against stored hash
- and you're done

> The problem with that is that any user specific data cannot be retrieved before authentication so I will need to chain an additional query in order to retrieve any extra user sensitive data and this process would seem janky.

You don't need a second query, if you don't want one. Rather than:

> SELECT PasswordHash FROM Users WHERE Username = %username%

use

> SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = %username%

Now you have all the user specific data returned with one question.